# Will a computer itself consume any energy if placed under super-conducting conditions?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, superconductivity

By definition, any electronic circuits placed under super-conducting conditions (very low temperatures) will not dissipate energy to the surroundings as the resistance is 0.

If a computer was placed under such conditions, would it consume any electric energy? The question only considers the energy changes within the computer, not the energy required to achieve extremely low temperatures.

I am asking this question because if a computer does not consume any energy under certain circumstances, it seems philosophically paradoxical that it can run simulations and create virtual environments that come out of nothing.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle

Comment: All superconductivity means is you don't get a voltage drop, but power might be needed for reasons other than $I^2R$.

Comment: It probably won't work at all. You'll have to design a new one out of superconductor.

Comment: Even if you could make a computer that used no power, any display or output device would need to use power.  Computing that does not output anything (or equivalently control a device) is just pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of superconductors comes into play for "the peripherals" on the board, so to speak, but at a fundamental level, computation is done by representing bits with a voltage threshold, and the manipulations of computation are done by raising and lowering those voltages. For the sake of argument, if $0$ is represented with ground voltage, then $1$ is represented with more than threshold voltage. Computational steps requiring changing a $0$ to $1$ thus require energy input, and those requiring changing a $1$ to a $0$ require energy output. In an ordinary computer, that output is all wasted. In effect, a tiny capacitor is discharged to ground through the conductive paths of the CPU architecture, and this is (a part of) the heat that develops in the CPU that the sink and fan carry away.

At the very least, a computer that attempted to recover all those discharging capacitors would run extremely slowly, as all reversible processes do. In addition, there are second law considerations, as the commenter who linked you to Landauer's principle is pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this question misses the point of computer circuitry. Yes, conductors are important, but what makes a computer do computations is not the conductors but rather the transistors. There is no such thing as a supertransistor.

It is unlikely that you could design a computer without components that consume energy. If it is possible at all then it would be a drastically different design than modern computers. The mentioned philosophical paradox is certainly not achieved simply through the use of superconductors to replace the conductors in a standard computer architecture.